# Display only selected properties from the class

Tags: c#, blazor

Assume, I like to display only `name` and `quantity` from the class (not "price"). How to set visible property for these fields in the ItemPoints.cs, which I could make use of in razor page to display only these two properties.

Below is my class:

ItemPoints.cs

```
public class ItemPoints : Points 
{        
    [JsonPropertyName("nme")]
    public double Name { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("Prc")]
    public double Price { get; set; }
  
    [JsonPropertyName("qty")]
    public double Quantity{ get; set; }    
 }
```

Razor page that displays these properties:

Item.Razor

```
   var type = typeof(ItemPoints); // I could pass different types here
   foreach (var item in type.GetProperties().Where(w => w.PropertyType == typeof(double)))
   {
         .......
   }
```

As you could see `var type = typeof(ItemPoints)`, I could pass different types here. So do not want to hardcode class name and property name in razor page. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use a custom attribute to mark properties that you doesn't want to display. Something like this.

```
public class HiddenAttribute : Attribute { }

public class ItemPoints : Points   {
    [JsonPropertyName("nme")]
    public double Name { get; set; }

    [Hidden]
    [JsonPropertyName("Prc")]
    public double Price { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("qty")]
    public double Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

And then exclude hidden properties from the `foreach`:

```
foreach (var item in type
              .GetProperties()
              .Where(w => 
                   w.PropertyType == typeof(double) && 
                   w.GetCustomAttribute<HiddenAttribute>() == null)) {

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Works perfect as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want this? Why don't you create a viewmodel with only the properties you want to display, map to that and send that to the view? If you insist on making this more "generic" (i.e. unfathomable for future you, the next developer and the time when a bug comes in and you need to debug stuff within your views) and using reflection, then:

- Opt-in using an attribute of your choosing. I'd pick `[DisplayName("Name")]`. Or create one yourself if that clashes with already-present attributes.
- Loop over all properties, get their custom attributes, if they contain `DisplayNameAttribute` (or whichever you picked), render them.

But again, I'd just go with a viewmodel. A class specifically crafted for the view it's required in.